# IIS SSL Vulnerabilities

Tags: iis

Our security scans are showing these vulnerabilities in IIS. I updated web.cfg and added this section and resetIIS, however the issue still exists. Any ideas how to resolve this?

```
<location path="Orion/Admin/Accounts/EditAccount.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="16096" executionTimeout="600" />
     </system.web>
     <system.web>
      <httpCookies httpOnlyCookies="true" requireSSL="true" />
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

3.2.1. Missing HttpOnly Flag From Cookie (http-cookie-http-only-flag)
3.2.2. Missing Secure Flag From SSL Cookie (http-cookie-secure-flag)

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following methods:

1.Enable HttpOnly Flag in IIS

Edit the web.config file of your web application and add the following:

```
<system.web>
   <httpCookies httpOnlyCookies="true" requireSSL="true" />
</system.web>
```

2.Enable Secure Flag in IIS

To enable secure flag in IIS, it is better to use URL Rewrite and add the following to your web.config file:

```
<system.webServer>
  <rewrite>
    <outboundRules>
       <rule name="Use only secure cookies" preCondition="Unsecured cookie">
          <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_SET_COOKIE" pattern=".*" negate="false" />
        <action type="Rewrite" value="{R:0}; secure" />
       </rule>
  <preConditions>
    <preCondition name="Unsecured cookie">
      <add input="{RESPONSE_SET_COOKIE}" pattern="." />
      <add input="{RESPONSE_SET_COOKIE}" pattern="; secure" negate="true" />
    </preCondition>
  </preConditions>
</outboundRules>
```